# Removing double quotes from a string in Apex

Tags: apex

How would I remove double quotes from a String in apex?

For example: I would expect "001023456567" to produce 001023456567, without the double quote.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
 String str ='"001023456567"';
 String temp=str.replace("/"","");
    
Unrecognized symbol '"', which is not a valid Apex identifier.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in Apex use single quotes. You can have double quotes inside of strings in Apex, but your error is stemming from tying to use double quotes outside of a string literal.

Bad

```java
String temp = str.replace("/"","");
```

Good

```java
// Notice how all of the double quotes (except for the one inside the replacement
//   string literal) have turned into single quotes
String temp = str.replace('"','');
```

Comment: That worked. will remember this for forever now.Thanks alot